# How can I get another HasMap from entry.getValue?

Tags: java, android

From For each loop, inside entry.getValue(), There is another map coming from firestore. How can I get?

Code:

```
  @Override
    public void onComplete (@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            //   binding.contentMain.noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                showLog("Data: " + document.getData());
                postMap.putAll(document.getData());
            }
            try {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : postMap.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getKey().equals(CONTENT)) {
                        showLog("value: " + entry.getValue().toString());


                        contentMap = new HashMap<>();
                        contentMap.putAll(entry.getValue());

                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            //  binding.contentMain.noData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            showLog("Error getting documents: " + task.getException());
        }
    }
```

I tried like below but compiler error. No suugestion:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
((Map)map.get( "keyname" )).get( "nestedkeyname" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
contentMap.putAll((Map<? extends String, ? extends Object>) entry.getValue());
```

Comment: Tried. But when I tried to retrieve it is coming in same line. See: for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : contentMap.entrySet()) {
                                                                showLog("value: " + entry.getValue().toString());
                                                            }

Comment: because you're casting entry value to String. Just do this `showLog("value: " + entry.getValue()); `

Comment: Tried that also. Still printing in one line instead of one by one

Comment: like this: value: {desc1=This is first, link1=xyz, desc2=hello, link2=fg}

Comment: When you Log a variable, even if its a map of key and values, it is printed as a string, so unless you iterate through the map and log every iteration, you will get everything all together like you are seeing it now

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: @sgtpotatoe I'm logging inside for each loop

Comment: @doublezofficial Working. Thank u so much dear!

Answer (score 0):

using your variable naming, try this

```
entry.iterator().next()
```

So if you have hashmap A:

```
{"key1":"value1",
"key2":"value2",
"key3":"value3"}
```

given the entryset of this hashMap "entrySet" you could do

```
entrySet.iterator().next()
```

which if used in a while loop can iterate throught all the key and values in the hashmap

Comment: iterator suggestion not coming